# Webpack force re-render (re-build, re-compile) via CLI webpack tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, webpack, frontend

Somethimes **webpack doesn't pick up my changes to jsx and scss files**, and hence it doesn't compile updated **main.scss** and **main.js**  (sometimes).

The webpack runs inside docker container installed in alpine linux light-weight environment.

I want to ssh into docker container and forcefully recompile the changes via webpack command line tool directly.

There might be some manual way like 
**$ webpack --force-complie or --force-watch** or something like that to manualy run the rebuild process of main.scss and main.js

is there any way to do so?

here is my **webpack.config.js** file:

```
    const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    require("dotenv").config();
}

module.exports = {
    entry: "./assets/shared/main.jsx",
    output: {
        path: "public",
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "eslint-loader"
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader?sourceMap!postcss-loader!sass-loader"
                )
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                // inline base64 URLs for <=4k images, direct URLs for the rest
                loader: "url-loader?limit=4096"
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    stats: { children: false },
    postcss: function () {
        return [autoprefixer];
    },
    eslint: {
        quiet: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
            "NODE_ENV", // This is used to run React in "production" mode
            "API_URL"
        ])
    ]
};
```